# infinite while loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, while-loop

My problem question as in the practice course goes as follows:

Write a JavaScript program to create a function which takes 2 integers as inputs. The function divides the first integer with second integer as long as the result (Quotient) is an integer (i.e. remainder is zero) and return the quotient as result. Your output code should be in the format console.log("Result is ", variableName)

And below is my code:

```
var num = prompt("Enter number to divide");
var d = prompt("Enter divisor");

function divide(x, y) {
  var result;
  if (d === 1) {
    result = num;
  } else {
    while (num % d === 0) { //while error
      result = num / d;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
var output = divide(num, d);
console.log("Result is: ", output);
```

If I remove the while loop, program works fine but the problem description says I have to use it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not changing `num` (nor `d`) but those are the only variables used in the condition `num%d===0`

Comment: The `while` depends on `num` and `d`. But neither of them is changed in the while's body, so the condition doesn't ever change. You probably want `result = num; while (result%d===0) result=result/d;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues:

**1)** If your function receives the arguments `x` and `y`, then use those inside his scope, don't access the global variables.

**2)** You are never changing the variables that are evaluated on the `while` condition, so the evaluation will be the same, ever!

**3)** Another good thing you can do is add some validation on the received arguments.

Now, your code, can be rearranged to this one:

```js
function divide(x, y)
{
    if (isNaN(x) || isNaN(y))
        return "Invalid arguments!";

    if (y === 1)
        return x;

    while (x % y === 0)
    {        
        x = x / y;
    }

    return x;
}

var num = prompt("Enter number to divide");
var d = prompt("Enter divisor");
var output = divide(num, d);
console.log("Result is: ", output);
```

Comment: This code works and passes all the test cases according to the website but when I enter "num=4" and "d=2" during execution,it returns result as "1.00" when it should return "2.00". Does the same for some other cases too.Any particular reason for that?

Comment: Well, `4 / 2 = 2` and remainder is `0`. Then `2 / 2 = 1` and remainder is `0`. Finally `1 / 2 = 0.5` (Note this operation is never executed) and remainder is `1`  (this result breaks the while loop) so the previous obtained result (`1`) is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop is depending of `num`, but you don´t assign a new value to it after a cycle. This lead to that the condition stays always the same.

```js
var num = prompt("Enter number to divide");
    var d = prompt("Enter divisor");

    function divide(x, y) {
      var result = x;
      if (y === 1) {
        return result;
      } else {
        while (result % y === 0) {
          result = result / y;
        }
      }
      return result;
    }
    var output = divide(num, d);
    console.log("Result is: ", output);
```